# How to browse Oracle's maven repository?

Tags: maven

Having recently walked into a new contract in the 1990's (you remember, where jar files were shared via email and called things like resourcebundle.jar - no, I'm not actually kidding) I am trying to work backwards and find groupId/artifactId/version identifiers for various Oracle ADF/BPEL/BPM/SOA etc libraries.

However, as the Oracle maven repository at https://maven.oracle.com isn't visible to a browser (new-fangled technology rubbish!) I'm at a loss to try and guess the identifiers for various Oracle-related jars.

Any thoughts? Thank you, Andrew (aka Marty McFly)

Comment: The maven repository needs a registration than you can it..? which is shown on the page if you try to access it via the browser (you newfangled technology)..

Comment: Sure, thanks, but that's not really the question...

Comment: If you have the registration than you can browe it so it's the answer...

Comment: Really @khmarbaise? http://www.oracle.com/webfolder/application/maven/index.html 
"...Directory browsing is not allowed on the Oracle Maven Repository..."
Look forward to hearing from you!

Comment: Here is a step by step to browse the Oracle's maven repository with "Nexus Repository OSS" http://www.fabriziomarini.com/2016/04/maven-oracle-how-to-mavenoraclecom.html

Comment: Thank you @pinei that article looks helpful. I will revisit this and hopefully confirm.

Answer (score 0):

The best way is to check on Oracle Documentation the list of groupId/ArtifactId/version.
For example for Adf:
https://docs.oracle.com/middleware/1213/core/MAVEN/adf_maven_project.htm#MAVEN8989

From this page you can find all the informations about: SOA, ADF, Coherence, OSB, BPM and other:
https://docs.oracle.com/middleware/1213/core/MAVEN/toc.htm

But for my experience, Oracle repository is not solid.
The best way is to configure your m2 directory from a your weblogic installation with your products (soa, bpm, etc.).
This is the official guide: https://docs.oracle.com/middleware/12213/wls/WLPRG/maven.htm#WLPRG587

Comment: omg Oracle maven is a joke. Official software distribution like "get it from product BIN" ... great